# When Python 3.2.3 isn't good enough

Tags: python-3.x, compatibility

Something I'm doing works under the latest Windows Python 2 and 3, latest Debian Python 2 and 3, and Cygwin Python 2, but fails under Cygwin Python 3.2.3.  Known bug fixes after 3.2.3 on Windows deal with the problem.

Where does that realistically leave me concerning deployment, if the latest version using traditional distribution paths (latest Cygwin Python 3) isn't high enough, should I:

- tell the user oops, wait for an upgrade
- tell the user to manually download a newer Python to shadow the official distro version
- tell the user to use Windows Python 3 instead of Cygwin Python 3 to run this program
- downgrade my code to stop using the multiprocessing class where bad things happen

I'm testing on six versions of Python right now and didn't even try OS X or BSD yet.  Are compatibility issues and having to downgrade code to just not use certain Python Standard Library classes something others have to do often?

Comment: Users using cygwin should have some idea of the implications of using cygwin. I'd recommend the Windows version as a workaround, but I'm no python expert.

Comment: Agreed.  Works on Linux and "Known to work on Windows Python" is enough to let anyone run my module, so this seems to be a minor edge condition, and not representative of Python in general which is robust.

Comment: One possible workaround/solution you didn't list: Depending on the bug, it might be possible to monkey-patch the library when you detect the affected python version(s). This is normally infeasible for functionality implemented in C, but I've had to do this a few times for python parts of the standard library - e.g. stopping python2.6 ElementTree from screwing up in the presence of namespaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept the answer from Billy ONeal in the comment above